# Организация маршрутов Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Содержание роута:

```
Route::get('category/{category}', 'Product_Controller@index');
```

Содержание контроллера:

```
$data = Category::where('alias', $category)
            ->firstOrfail();
```

Запись в базе данных:

```
поле alias = 'category/subcategory'

При переходе на страницу site.com/category/subcategory выдает ошибку: 
(1/1) NotFoundHttpException
```

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените описание маршрута следующим образом:

```
Route::get('category/{category}', 'Product_Controller@index')
    ->where(['category' => '(.*)']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Вместо

```
$data = Category::where('alias', $category)
            ->firstOrfail();
```

Сделайте

```
$data = Category::where('alias', "category/{$category}")
            ->firstOrfail();
```